# Why copying a character to a char array results in weird behaviour

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have the following code which aims to implemente a simple LZW based text compression:

```
int compress(FILE text_file, FILE *output) {
  char input[20];
  short code = 0;
  short size = 0;

  memset(input, '\0', 20);
  
  char c = fgetc(text_file);
  while (c != EOF) {
    strncat(input, &c, 1);
    code = getCodeFromInput(input);
    if ((size + 1) > 1 && code == -1) {
      addInput(input);
      fwrite(&code, 2, 1, output);
      strcpy(input, &c);
      printf(%s, input);
      size = 1;
      code = 0;
    } else {
      size++;
    }
    c = fgetc(text_file);
  }
  fwrite(&input, 2, 1, output);
  return 0;
 }
```

So after finding a suitable string I need to override my string `input` with with the last `char` I've received. When using `strcpy()` I can easily copy arrays to my `input` string, but when trying to copy a single character, if I print the result I will get the expected output plus some weird character, for example copying the caracter 'a' I get `a�`. Is this expected? Why does `strcpy()` behave like that?

Comment: `strcpy()` will read characters until it reaches a null character. You probably want to use `strncpy()` which only copies the number of characters that you tell it too.

Comment: I think you are trying to copy a file, so why don't you just use fwrite() inside the loop for each character? You can simplify the code by removing the variable input, since it can create segmentation failts due to its size. In case you want to monitor the characters read you can simply use printf("%c", c);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard defines `strcpy` as a function copying a NUL terminated string, you are copying the last input (a character), but even if you get his address, it is not a NUL terminated string:

```
strcpy(input, &c);
```

you can try using a compound literal:

```
strcpy(input, (char[2]){c, '\0'}); // A NUL terminated string
```

Also, notice that `fgetc` wants an `int` instead of a `char` in order to handle `EOF`:

```
char c = fgetc(text_file);
```

should be

```
int c = fgetc(text_file);
```

in consequence:

```
strcpy(input, (char[2]){(char)c, '\0'}); // A NUL terminated string
```